# Change Slick Slider Arrow Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I want to change **slick slider arrow** position as same in the picture but i am unable to acheive the same in jquery .

[image]

```
$('.your-class').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    prevArrow:'<i class=" fas fa-angle-right clr-gry"></i>',
    nextArrow:'<i class="fas fa-angle-left clr-gry"></i>'

});
```

Comment: Looks like more of a css issue than a javascript one, can you post the styles you're applying?

Comment: I haven't apply any css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add Class on your Slick function like

```
prevArrow: $(".pp2"),
nextArrow: $(".nn2"),
```

& Below button add with style :

```
<button class="pp2">back</button>
<button class="nn2">forward</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of arrows using CSS.  Try like below

```
.clr-gry.slick-arrow {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.fa-angle-left.clr-gry {
    right: 10px;
}

.fa-angle-right.clr-gry {
    right: 0;
}
```

If this not work, please share the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

`.slick-next` and `.slick-prev` are pre-defined classes in slick slider. For customizing the CSS of arrow you can use these classes to get your desired result.

Works whether you are using jQuery or React.